# get selected textbox id jQuery

Tags: jquery

In my form I have several textboxes like `txtItemCode1`, `txtItemCode2`, etc.

I use this code to perform some action if I press enter on any of these, but I want to get the selected textbox id. How can I do that?

Comment: selected textbox..? pls show the cpde

Answer (score 10, accepted):

variable id should have what you are looking for.

```
$('input[type="text"]').change(function(){
     var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In the event that you have bound to your textbox's to perform actions on enter, use this to get the `id` of the textbox you pressed enter on.

```
$(this).attr('id')
```

or

```
this.id
```