# how to reuse selected id via jquery to perform $.trim() function

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I found this link very useful

[get selected textbox id jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8220893/get-selected-textbox-id-jquery)

however, what i wanted to do now is to reuse this id to do some trimming function for each textbox where it is actually looping. I have tried this code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <?php   echo $this->Html->script("jquery-1.4.3.min"); ?>

    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        echo $content_for_layout;
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
         //       alert('JQuery is succesfully included');

/*      $(':submit').click(function(){
            <?php if(($this->request->controller=='members')&&($this->action=='register')):?>
                    //alert('well');
                    var some = $.trim($(":text").val());
                    alert(some);
            <?php  endif; ?>

            });
*/
            $(':submit').click(function(){
                $('form input[type="text"]').each(function(){
                    //get value of id of textbox here
                    var id = $(this).attr('id');
                    var some = $.trim($((this).attr('id')).val());
                    alert(some);
                });

            });
        });
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

yet it doesnt pops out the alert box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a bit confused about exactly what you are trying to achieve, but there is a problem on this line:

```
var some = $.trim($((this).attr('id')).val());
```

Specifically, `(this).attr('id')` doesn't work because `(this)` is interpreted as `this` and `this` is the current DOM element which doesn't have an `.attr()` method.

I *think* you probably wanted to do this:

```
var some = $.trim($("#" + $(this).attr('id')).val());
// or, given you already have a variable id equal to $(this).attr('id')
var some = $.trim($('#' + id).val());
```

That is, you are trying to get the id from the current element then use that id to select the element and get its value, then trim the value. But you don't need the id to get the value given you already have a reference to the element - you can just do this:

```
var some = $.trim($(this).val());
// or
var some = $.trim(this.value);
```

If you want to loop through all the textboxes and set them to the trimmed version of their current values you can do this:

```
$('form input[type="text"]').each(function(){
    this.value = $.trim(this.value);
    // or if you want the slower and harder to read way:
    $(this).val( $.trim($(this).val()) );
});
```

Or:

```
$('form input[type="text"]').val(function(i,currentVal) {
    return $.trim(currentVal);
});
```

See the [`.val()` doco](http://api.jquery.com/val/) for information about passing a callback function to `.val()`.